# build all and deploy error in 5.0.6

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

build all and deploy error in 5.0.6 
 --

create one empty worklight project, build all and depoy......then the error in the console as blow.......

Thanks in advance...

```
[2013-03-21 21:54:00]             Worklight Server started successfully on localhost:8080
[2013-03-21 21:54:00]             Activating Worklight project: SDMobileBank...
[2013-03-21 21:54:06]             Activation failed. Bundle didn't start:D:\Worklight_workspace\SDMobileBank\bin\SDMobileBank-customization.jar
[2013-03-21 21:54:32]             Activating Worklight project: SDMobileBank...
[2013-03-21 21:54:32]             Worklight Server stopped successfully on localhost:8080
[2013-03-21 21:54:34]             Worklight Server started successfully on localhost:8080
[2013-03-21 21:54:41] FWLSE2001I: Detected more than one IP address. Using 192.168.25.45 as the public IP address of the Worklight Server. You can set a different IP address in worklight.properties.
[2013-03-21 21:54:44] FWLSE3005I: Application raw reports are disabled.
[2013-03-21 21:54:44] FWLST0010I: ====== Started server for project SDMobileBank-project-customization; Worklight version=5.0.6.20130307-1147
[2013-03-21 21:54:44]             Activation done.
[2013-03-21 21:54:48]             Persistency data access problem
                                  com.worklight.core.exceptions.DefaultExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultExceptionHandler.java:50)
                                  com.worklight.core.tasks.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:100)
[2013-03-21 21:54:51]             Starting build process: application 'SDMobileBank', all environments
[2013-03-21 21:54:51] FWLSE2001I: Detected more than one IP address. Using 192.168.25.45 as the public IP address of the Worklight Server. You can set a different IP address in the application descriptor files of your applications.
[2013-03-21 21:54:53]             Application 'SDMobileBank' with all environments build finished.
[2013-03-21 21:54:53]             Deploying application 'SDMobileBank' with all environments to Worklight Server...
[2013-03-21 21:54:53]             Persistency data access problem
                                  com.worklight.core.exceptions.DefaultExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultExceptionHandler.java:50)
                                  com.worklight.core.tasks.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:100)
[2013-03-21 21:54:56]             Application 'SDMobileBank' deployed successfully with all environments
[2013-03-21 21:54:59]             Persistency data access problem
                                  com.worklight.core.exceptions.DefaultExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultExceptionHandler.java:50)
                                  com.worklight.core.tasks.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:100)
[2013-03-21 21:55:04]             Persistency data access problem
                                  com.worklight.core.exceptions.DefaultExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultExceptionHandler.java:50)
                                  com.worklight.core.tasks.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:100)
[2013-03-21 21:55:09]             Persistency data access problem
                                  com.worklight.core.exceptions.DefaultExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultExceptionHandler.java:50)
                                  com.worklight.core.tasks.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:100)
[2013-03-21 21:55:14]             Persistency data access problem
                                  com.worklight.core.exceptions.DefaultExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultExceptionHandler.java:50)
                                  com.worklight.core.tasks.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:100)
```

---

some times ,the error..

```
[2013-03-21 21:43:12]             user lacks privilege or object not found: 
T0.MULTILANGUAGE_MESSAGES {SELECT t0.ID, t0.ACTION, t0.CREATED_TIME, t0.DOWNLOAD_LINK, t0.ENV, t0.GADGET_NAME, t0.MESSAGE, t0.MULTILANGUAGE_MESSAGES, t0.VERSION FROM APP_VERSION_ACCESS_DATA t0 
WHERE (t0.GADGET_NAME = ? AND t0.ENV = ? AND t0.VERSION = ?)} 
[code=-5501, state=42501]; nested exception is 
<openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal general error> 
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: 
user lacks privilege or object not found: T0.MULTILANGUAGE_MESSAGES {
SELECT t0.ID, t0.ACTION, t0.CREATED_TIME, t0.DOWNLOAD_LINK, t0.ENV, t0.GADGET_NAME, t0.MESSAGE, 
t0.MULTILANGUAGE_MESSAGES, t0.VERSION FROM APP_VERSION_ACCESS_DATA t0 WHERE (t0.GADGET_NAME = ? AND t0.ENV = ? AND t0.VERSION = ?)} [code=-5501, state=42501]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The database schema has changed in v5.0.6. This should have been made clearer, and will be addressed.
Database upgrades are not supported in the Developer Edition.

To resolve this issue:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Delete the WorklightServerHome folder located in the Eclipse workspace folder.
3. Restart Eclipse
4. Build your application.

The operation should now pass without errors.