# Worklight didn't automatic create android project folder

Tags: android, eclipse, project, ibm-mobilefirst

I have one problem, i try to edit my project, to add canvas. (from here [IBM Worklight - Using Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991653/ibm-worklight-using-canvas)) but it didn't work, and i try to clean my project. then i change code just to open new page, but it didn't work. so i try to delete project android that automatically create when i check list option on Worklight Environment.

then i try to build again. but project android didn't automatically created again. so i try to restart my eclipse, then delete WorklightServerHome folder located in the Eclipse workspace folder. (based on this thread [build all and deploy error in 5.0.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549667/build-all-and-deploy-error-in-5-0-6/15551643#15551643)), but it didn't work either. anyone can help me to make project android it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you actually mean is that you deleted the android folder (environment) from your project, rather than the generated Android project...

1. Open `application-descriptor.xml` and delete the `<android> ... </android>` section
2. Click on the Worklight icon in the toolbar and choose to add a new Worklight environment
3. Choose the Android environment

If that's not what you meant, please edit the question to make the question clearer...

Comment: thank you for your solution. i get my android folder (environment) back. and sorry for my english.